# How to save the results of calculations in a variable

Tags: stata

I have multiple lines of `proportion calculations`, like this:

```
proportion DIAEDUC
```

This command gives me the following result:

```
Proportion estimation             Number of obs   =     10,802

--------------------------------------------------------------
             |                                   Logit
             | Proportion   Std. Err.     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+------------------------------------------------
DIAEDUC      |
           0 |    .972774   .0025372      .9673336    .9773295
           1 |    .027226   .0025372      .0226705    .0326664
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is there a way to save the value `.027226` in a variable?

Comment: Please read the [Stata tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stata/info) for advice on how to ask Stata-related questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results are returned to the `e(b)` matrix:

```
sysuse auto, clear

proportion foreign

Proportion estimation             Number of obs   =         74

--------------------------------------------------------------
             | Proportion   Std. Err.     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+------------------------------------------------
foreign      |
    Domestic |   .7027027   .0534958      .5865827    .7974684
     Foreign |   .2972973   .0534958      .2025316    .4134173
--------------------------------------------------------------

matrix list e(b)

e(b)[1,2]
     foreign:  foreign:
    Domestic   Foreign
y1  .7027027  .2972973
```

You can then store the result of interest in a variable as follows:

```
matrix A = e(b)
generate result = A[1,2]

list result in 1

     +----------+
     |   result |
     |----------|
  1. | .2972973 |
     +----------+
```